# Curl: Can't connect to SOCKS5 proxy on server

Tags: php, curl

I'm having the weirdest issue...

On my local machine, if I run this, it works (IP censored):

```
curl -x socks5://x.x.x.x:1080 --proxy-user anon:anon -L https://ip.me
x.x.x.x
```

However, if I run this on my server, I get this...

```
curl -x socks5://x.x.x.x:1080 --proxy-user anon:anon -L https://ip.me
curl: (97) Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to ip.me. (2)
```

Now, **on the server**, if I run

```
nmap -p 1080 x.x.x.x
```

It reports that the port is open and that the service is "socks".

I also tried running `dpkg-reconfigure` on curl but no dice.

**Edit**

I also tried connecting to the proxy from *another* machine, and it works. It really seems to be an issue on my OVH VPS specifically...

**Edit #2**

I just configured `proxychains` and used it on `wget`. I was able to connect to the proxy just fine, but curl still errors out...

**Edit #3**

I just compiled curl from source, I'm still getting the same connectivity issue.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am so irrationally angry at this realization

Even if the proxy works elsewhere using `socks5`, try using `socks5h`.

Hopefully I can save someone 3 hours of their lives...